# Docker Error with NVIDIA GPU: libnvidia-ml.so.1 Not Found Despite Successful nvidia-smi and Driver Detection

Tags: docker, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm facing an issue when trying to run an NVIDIA GPU-supported Docker container on my system. Despite successful detection of NVIDIA drivers and GPUs via `nvidia-smi`, attempting to run a Docker container with the command `docker run --rm --gpus all ubuntu:18.04 nvidia-smi` results in the following error:

```bash
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy' nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.
Here's the output of nvidia-smi, showing that the NVIDIA drivers and GPUs are correctly detected and operational:
```

```bash
$ nvidia-smi
Thu Feb 22 02:39:45 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000    On   | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| 30%   37C    P8    14W / 230W |  11671MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA RTX A5000    On   | 00000000:86:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| 55%   80C    P2   211W / 230W |  13119MiB / 23028MiB |     79%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

To troubleshoot, I ran nvidia-container-cli -k -d /dev/tty info, which confirmed that the NVIDIA libraries, including libnvidia-ml.so.525.85.12, are detected. However, the Docker error persists, suggesting an issue with locating libnvidia-ml.so.1.

So far, I've attempted:

Reinstalling NVIDIA drivers and CUDA Toolkit.
Reinstalling NVIDIA Container Toolkit.
Ensuring Docker and NVIDIA Container Toolkit are correctly configured.
Setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to NVIDIA libraries.
Despite these efforts, the problem remains unresolved. I'm operating on a Linux system with NVIDIA driver version 525.85.12.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

#### What I Tried:

1. Running a Docker Container with NVIDIA GPU Support: You attempted to start a Docker container using the NVIDIA GPU with the command `docker run --rm --gpus all ubuntu:18.04 nvidia-smi`.
2. Checking NVIDIA Driver and GPU Detection: You used nvidia-smi to ensure that the NVIDIA drivers and GPUs were correctly detected and operational on your system.
3. Diagnostic with NVIDIA Container Toolkit: You ran nvidia-container-cli -k -d /dev/tty info to diagnose the issue, which confirmed that the NVIDIA libraries, including libnvidia-ml.so.525.85.12, were detected by your system.
4. Attempted Solutions for Resolution:

   - Reinstalling NVIDIA Container Toolkit to ensure proper integration with Docker.
   - Setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to NVIDIA libraries, attempting to resolve any issues related to the library path.

#### What You Were Expecting:

- Successful Container Initialization: You expected the Docker container to initialize successfully with NVIDIA GPU support, allowing you to use GPU resources within the container.
- Resolution of Library Detection Issue: You anticipated that the steps taken would resolve any issues related to the detection of libnvidia-ml.so.1, ensuring that Docker and the NVIDIA Container Toolkit could access and utilize the necessary NVIDIA libraries.
- Operational GPU Support in Docker: Ultimately, you expected these troubleshooting steps to enable seamless GPU support within Docker containers, allowing for GPU-accelerated applications to run as intended.

The discrepancy between the expected outcomes and the actual results – the persistent error message indicating an inability to find libnvidia-ml.so.1 despite confirmed detection of NVIDIA drivers and libraries – suggests that there might be an underlying issue with the Docker and NVIDIA integration setup, library paths, or possibly with specific versions of the tools and drivers involved.

Comment: [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ubuntu/18.04/images/sha256-dca176c9663a7ba4c1f0e710986f5a25e672842963d95b960191e2d9f7185ebe?context=explore)

Comment: The command you mention at the start of your question, `docker run --rm --gpus all ubuntu:18.04 nvidia-smi`, does not seem to be possible since `nvidia-smi` is not installed on a bare `ubuntu:18.04` container. Are you working with an image _derived_ from `ubuntu:18.04`?